# VS2015 Updatate 3 CodeMap always crashes

Tags: visual-studio

Codemap is an awesome tool, but since updating to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3 it no longer works.

It starts to load, and generates a compacted version but when clicking on the expand it crashes with the following:

> Unable to connect to the specified database.
> An exception occurred attempting to connect to a database using the following connection string:
> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous Processing=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30.
>
> Check that the specified SQL Server instance exists and the service is running.

Any ideas? Google is no help :-)

Comment: Try to "Check that the specified SQL Server instance exists and the service is running."

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to CodeMap, which I was not aware of. Have you tried [Supercharger](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2) as the recommended enhanced version of CodeMap? It runs in my installation of VS2015 Update 3 (Community Edition).

Comment: Thanks MegaTron, but this has never happened in the past, I imagine it is generating a local db on the fly to hold the data as it creates a map of the solution. Not only that but there is no db name in the string.

Comment: Axel, the supercharger, which I installed when looking for a solution, is different from the Codemap which is build into VS. The built in one is under the Architecture Menu and produces a visual diagram with expandable nodes, that show the design of the solution. Its awesome.